# Ошибки при подключении прокси Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Подскажите что это за ошибка и как ее исправить, раньше дело с прокси не имел
http://joxi.ru/5mdg495HvBoZar
http://joxi.ru/p27aKYvi0VXjYr

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError.com.adservice.JobService
```